# SXA placeholder settings not limiting renderings

Tags: sxa, presentation

I've added a placeholder to a rendering variant.

When I use that variant on a page, I click on the add item button, and I get the default window with all renderings available.  I have then added a placeholder setting item, and put the key in the placeholder key of the placeholder in the variant.  I still see all renderings when I go to add an item.

One issue I noticed is if I try to edit the placeholder setting in the experience editor it's not picking up the correct item due to the -1-1 that are getting added to the placeholder setting

[image: placeholdersettingedit]

Does anyone have any idea what I need to do to correct this?

Here is my placeholder setting

[image: placeholdersetting]

And here is my placeholder in the variant

[image: renderingvariant]

I've tried this with and without the * to indicate a dynamic placeholder.

Comment: Can you update your question with screenshot of actual placeholder settings found under site/Placeholder Settings/featuredvideo?

Comment: @PeterProcházka sorry for forgetting about these earlier, I've added them now.

Comment: Did you try putting `featuredvideo*` in the placeholder key in the placeholder setting? That should work.

Comment: @Gatogordo yep, that did it. I could have sworn I'd tried that configuration, but evidently I hadn't, thank you.

Comment: I'll add it as answer as soon as I get back at my laptop..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `featurevideo*` in the placeholder key of the placeholder setting.

The placeholders in the rendering variant are dynamic, which explains the -1-1 addition to the key you provided in the variant. To capture those dynamic additions, you need to use wildcards in the placeholder key.